# Measurability of Interior and closure of a non-measurable set.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I was thinking about this question -

Let $E$ be a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$, then what can be said about the measurability of $int(E)$ and $\overline{E}$ ? .

I know the fact that any subset of a measurable set need not be measurable (example - Vitali's construction of non-measurable set.)

Also as per the definition of $int(E)$ is the union of open sets contained in $E$ and I think as the open sets are measurable and union of measurable sets being measurable so $nt(E)$ is measurable.

Also similarly for $\overline{E}$ since closure of $E$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $E$, and closed sets are measurable,also intersection of measurable sets being measurable implies $\overline{E}$ is also measurable.

I doubt my method as I have nowhere used the non-measurability of $E$.
But how can we proceed if the set is non-measurable?

Comment: How they can different measures?any reference ?

Comment: I have turned my Comment into an Answer, with explanation and references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say open and closed sets are measurable, so the interior and the closure of **any** set are measurable.

Comment: Nice now how about this $Int(E) \cup \{\frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $ \bar{E} \cup \{\frac{1}{n};n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ ?, I think $\{\frac{1}{n};n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable set and hence measure is 0 implying measurable so both the latter sets are measurable ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Any speciality of subsets of non-measurable sets like in the question comment above ?

Answer (score 2):

Since the phrasing asks "what can be said" about the Lesbegue measurability of $int(E)$ and $\overline{E}$ for a *non-measurable* set $E \subset [0,1]$, I would want to add the observation that the measures of $int(E)$ and $\overline{E}$ must differ.

This is easily seen because $int(E)\subseteq E\subseteq \overline{E}$.  Therefore were it the case that $m(int(E)) = m(\overline{E})$, we would have $m(\overline{E}\setminus int(E))=0$. Then it would follow from the [completeness of Lebesgue measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791021/proof-that-the-lebesgue-measure-is-complete) that the set $E$ would be measurable (with measure equal to both that of $int(E)$ and $\overline{E}$).

But since $E$ is assumed to be non-measurable, it must be that:
$$m(int(E)) \neq m(\overline{E}) $$

Comment: Nice thought! .