# Show that if f is Lebesgue measurable and f = g almost everywhere with respect to Lebesgue measure, then g is Lebesgue measurble.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Show that if $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable and $f=g$ a.e with respect to Lebesgue measure, then $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is also Lebesgue measurable.

I've been looking up solutions but I can't quite understand why any subset of the measurable set that has measure 0 is also measurable.

Comment: This comes from the fact that Lebesgue measure is [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791021/proof-that-the-lebesgue-measure-is-complete) for elements of the proof.

Comment: That is a property of *complete measures* and the Lebesgue measure is a complete measure. If you start with an outer measure and restrict the outer measure (with Caratheodory) to the the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets then the result is a complete measure. That process also gives birth to the Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $g^{-1}(\{y|y<m\})=\{x|g(x) < m\}=\{x|g(x)<m  \text{ and } g(x)=f(x)\} \cup \{x|g(x)<m  \text{ and } g(x) \neq f(x)\}$.

The second set in the union has measure $0$ and hence measurable. The first set in the union is $\{x|g(x)<m\} \cap (\mathbb{R}-\ \{x|g(x)\neq f(x)\})$ is measurable.

As complement of measurable set is measurable and intersection of measurable set is measurable?